# "Когда" и "где" — союзные слова или союзы?

Tags: синтаксис, спп, союзы

> Он отыскал свой класс, собрал всех своих учеников, и они построились парами, как строились, **когда** шли на урок.
>
> Мне захотелось немедленно отправиться в город-крепость, **где** сейчас тускло горели фонари, висящие на цепях, и ставни были закрыты.

Чем являются выделенные слова - подчинительными союзами или союзными словами?

По-моему, союзными словами, но есть и другие мнения. Хотелось бы узнать ваше.

Comment: Можете изложить "другие мнения"? На основании чего, как это формулируется. Дело в том, что употребление слова "союз" вместо "союзного слова" вполне возможно, если нет необходимости их противопоставления. И пожалуйста, не удаляйте вопросы сразу, как только вас попросили что- то уточнить. Если конечно не хотите, что бы вас связали  с тем автором, чьи манеры тут слишком хорошо знакомы...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Союзы и союзные слова различаются **по синтаксической роли** : союз - это **служебное слово,**  а союзное слово - **член предложения**.  Формальное различие? Нет, не совсем, так как эта классификация в действительности тесно связана **со структурой предложения**.

Все СПП можно разделить **на три принципиально различных группы**: **а) местоименная** (взаимообусловленная)  связь с союзными словами (это определительные придаточные и часть обстоятельственных - образа действия, степени, места, иногда времени); **б) союзная связь** (большая часть обстоятельственных придаточных); **в) изъяснительные придаточные** (в основном союзы и союзные слова в качестве варианта).

1) Он отыскал свой класс, собрал всех своих учеников, и они построились парами, как строились, **когда** шли на урок.  Формально это **союз**, но для союза КОГДА граница очень размытая. Это слово считается (также формально) **союзом** при отсутствии указательного слово тогда,  при его наличии это **союзное слово** и местоименная связь (тогда- когда). (Но всё это касается именно союза КОГДА.

**Примечание для пояснения темы**: Сравним: (1) Они построились парами, **когда** пошли на урок. Главное предложение самодостаточное (придаточное можно убрать), это  союз. (2) Они строились парами **(всегда), когда** шли на урок. Здесь ситуация в первом предложении требует продолжения, предложения взаимосвязаны по смыслу, но подстановка местоимения уже переводит союз в союзное слово. Именно поэтому роль "**когда" в заданном предложении сложно определить:** формально - союз, а неформально - союзное слово с пропущенным местоимением.

2) Мне захотелось немедленно отправиться в город-крепость, **где** сейчас тускло горели фонари, висящие на цепях, и ставни были закрыты.

Это **классическая местоименная связь**, придаточное определительное относится к существительному "город-крепость", **ГДЕ - союзное слово,** его можно заменить  союзным словом **В КОТОРОМ**. Интересно, что в этом случае **нельзя использовать указательное слово** (в тот город-крепость), так как это распространительный тип придаточного предложения (как бы способ описать две ситуации): (1)Мне захотелось немедленно отправиться в город-крепость, (2)в этой крепости сейчас тускло горели фонари, висящие на цепях, и ставни были закрыты.

Answer (score 2):

Я не вижу причин отказывать здесь "где" и "когда" вправе быть членами предложения (обстоятельствами места  или времени), поэтому они вполне могут трактоваться как союзные слова.

Что, конечно, не исключает понимания того, что по сути это те же союзы, особенно в старой терминологии.

Вообще в некоторых случаях граница весьма размыта.

Вот хотя бы у Кузнецова любопытные примеры.

II. союзн. сл. 1. Употр. в придат. предложениях определит. *В тот день, когда пришла телеграмма, его не было дома*. 2. Употр. в придат. предложениях дополнит. *Я не знаю, когда он вернётся. Мы поинтересовались, когда приходит поезд. Когда поехать, я ещё не решил.*

III. союз. 1. Употр. в начале придаточного предложения времени, внося общее значение соотнесённости во времени действий или состояний главного и придаточного предложений. *Когда идёт этот фильм, пустых мест в зрительном зале нет. Когда началась война, моему отцу было двадцать лет. Каждый раз, когда я прихожу в этот дом, я чувствую дружеское расположение. Когда машина остановилась, из неё вышли двое неизвестных.*

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0&all=x

Я бы не рискнул сформулировать четки отличия кузнецовских "*придаточного предложения времени*" и "*придат. предложениях определит*", она где-то на понятийном уровне сидит.